# net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 with proxy server

Tags: web, nginx, proxy, http2, spdy

In our project we're using 2 servers: 1 as a PROD API server and 1 as a proxy(actually nginx is used for that)

The proxy server uses HTTP/2 as well. In one scenario the proxy may get response from prod API server and replace PROD links by Proxy's and then return that to the client.

In that case we can catch the "**net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200**" error. I googled little bit about that issue, but it looks like it may be few reasons for that error.

In my case it occurs only when we replace hosts(modify the response from the PROD before sending it to client)

Can someone describe what actually the "**net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200**" means and maybe best practices to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTTP/2** is derived from the earlier **SPDY** protocol, that's probably why the error message doesn't mention HTTP/2 at all.

One of the reasons why you may see the **ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR** message is an invalid HTTP header coming from the server.  Perhaps your proxy is making some change to an HTTP response header which is [making it invalid/malformed](https://www.michalspacek.com/chrome-err_spdy_protocol_error-and-an-invalid-http-header)?

Try to disable HTTP/2 on your proxy server and see if the error goes away.  If it does, inspect the response headers and make sure they are valid.  I suspect your proxy server is malforming the response.

Comment: Thanks for help with. After HTTP/2 disabling it says the content type length mismatch error, actually nginx settings decided that rewriting procedure like MITM-atack

Comment: As soon as we found an issue we re-designed our approach, so we didn't resolved that length mismatch

Comment: I've solved the issue adding "proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;" to nginx proxy configuration.

Answer (score 2):

We met similar issue today when running the reverse proxy server using docker image: nginx:1.16.0-alpine. After changing to use nginx:1.16.0, this issue was solved.